# MongoDB $lookup on array of object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have 2 collections structured as below. I have tried $lookup to get the result but I am not getting any result because of my local and foreign fields are in array of object.

Below is my structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5795a3531d3f3afc19caefef"),
    "name" : "category1",
    "updatedAt" : "1469431592786",
    "resources" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5791be003fa3bedc15d3adde"),
            "title" : "resource1",
            "availability" : false
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5795a3771d3f3afc19caeff0"),
            "title" : "resource2",
            "availability" : true
        }
    ]

}
```

Above "categories" schema have resources array of object. this resource _id is stored in bookings collection in following way:

```
"booking":
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57960aa8000ca7a46b7ef683"),
    "name" : "1469491200000",
    "__v" : 0,
    "schedule" : [ 
        {
            "resourceId" : ObjectId("5791be003fa3bedc15d3adde"),
            "userId" : ObjectId("5791be003fa3bedc15d3adcve"),
            "title" : "grofep",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57960aa8f9f9951c1fc923b1")
        },
        {
            "resourceId" : ObjectId("5791be003fa3bedc15d3bddz"),
            "userId" : ObjectId("5791be003fa3bedc15d3adcve"),
            "title" : "mr3",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57960aa8f9f9951c1fc923b2")
        },
        {
            "resourceId" : ObjectId("5791be003fa3bedc15d3adde"),
            "userId" : ObjectId("5791be003fa3bedc15d3adcve"),
            "title" : "grofep23",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57960aa8f9f9951c1fc923b3")
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to get all the schedule of booking collection with their resource information.I want to fetch resources from categories table on the basis of booking schedule.
Desired output:

```
[
    {
        "name" : "1469491200000",
        "resourceId" : ObjectId("5791be003fa3bedc15d3adde"),
        "resourceTitle":"title",
        "availability":false,
        "bookings": [
            {
                "userId" : ObjectId("5791be003fa3bedc15d3adcve"),
                "title" : "grofep",
                "_id" : ObjectId("57960aa8f9f9951c1fc923b1")
            },
            {
                "userId" : ObjectId("5791be003fa3bedc15d3adcve"),
                "title" : "grofep23",
                "_id" : ObjectId("57960aa8f9f9951c1fc923b3")
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name" : "1469491200000",
        "resourceId" : ObjectId("5791be003fa3bedc15d3bddz"),
        "resourceTitle":"mr3",
        "availability":false,
        "bookings": [
            {
                "userId" : ObjectId("5791be003fa3bedc15d3adcve"),
                "title" : "mr3",
                "_id" : ObjectId("57960aa8f9f9951c1fc923b2")
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Help me to get this desired result.
Thanks.

Comment: It will be better if you post your `schema`s here and ask what you want, rather than showing what the document looks like. it is confusing from your question what you want. Please edit the code and rephrase the question. This way we would be able to help better.

Comment: @ravishankar this is the similar schema that I have posted here. I think key types will not help you to answer it.